# Where can I find an easy to use database with the latitude and longitude of ZIP Codes in America?

Tags: database, c#

Hi I have found a few text-based databases online with ZIP codes and their corresponding latitude and longitude, but all of them are very difficult to read, are filled with junk extraneous information I don't need, are outdated, or have a lot of missing information. Can someone please give me a link to a good database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a cvs and dataset: https://www.boutell.com/zipcodes/

For a text file:  https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666

Additional sites: 
https://www.zipinfo.com/products/z5ll/z5ll.htm

http://federalgovernmentzipcodes.us

Comment: I was using the one from github and I finally found out why it wasn't working. There isn't a space between the latitude and the next zipcode numbers making it really difficult to extract numbers since my program will treat this as one number.

Comment: The last 2 looked interesting as they both had multiple formats.